# How to get response from all pages in SuperTest jest

Tags: javascript, supertest

I am using super test and In the above code, I want to get all pages response, the page attribute I am sending as Params.

```
const query = { country: USA, language: english, currency: USD, page: 1 }
getRequest(query) {
    const response = request.agent(https://www.baseurl)
      .get(/endpoint)
      .query(query)
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status !== 200) {
          throw new Error(`${res.status} ${res.error}`);
        } else {
          return res;
        }
      });
    return response
  }
```

Comment: > Complete code is as below:-







`
const request = require("supertest");
const query = { country: USA, language: english, currency: USD, page: 1 }
getRequest(query) {
const response = request.agent(https://www.baseurl)
  .get(/endpoint)
  .query(query)
  .set('Accept', 'application/json')
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  .then(res => {
    if (res.status !== 200) {
      throw new Error(`${res.status} ${res.error}`);
    } else {
      return res;
    }
  });
return response}`

Comment: Please add the source code in the question and not as a comment, it's easier for others to help you this way. Thanks!